# Can grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 80px) be used interchangeably with grid-auto-rows: 80px?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'd like the grid to add more rows as necessary when dynamic content is added.

And this does the trick:

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 80px;
  grid-auto-rows: 80px;
//  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 80px);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(340px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 60px 60px;
}
```

I'm wondering if instead of using `grid-auto-rows: 80px` we can use `grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 80px);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 80px);` is a valid declaration according to [the specs](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#track-sizing), but it doesn't give the desired result. Instead, it just creates one explicit row with a height of 80px and the additional rows are auto-sized.

However, since you are wanting to add rows as necessary, i.e. implicitly-created grid rows, you should be using [`grid-auto-rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-rows) and there's no need to use `grid-template-rows`.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 80px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(340px, 1fr));
  gap: 60px;
  }

.grid div {
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
<div>content</div>
<div>content</div>
<div>content</div>
<div>content</div>
<div>content</div>
<div>content</div>
<div>content</div>
<div>content</div>
</div>
```